# How can I center horizontally children inside col-xs-12 div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's my code.

```
<div class="pull-right" style="display:flex">  
    <div><img src="80x150 image"/></div>
    <div><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy Policy</a></div>
</div>
```

I would like to center horizontally the div with image and the one with  link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it is what you are looking for but you can simply add mx-auto class for horizontally centering. Don't forget to set the width of the element you want to center.

For instance:

```
<div class="mx-auto" style="width: 200px;"><img src="80x150 image"/></div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You can imporve an answer by showing and foramting the code. This will help the OP and future visitors

Comment: Thanks for the help @C0G1T0. Now I'm looking for. way to center them vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Simply You can use align center class witn col-xs-12

```
<div align="center" class="col-xs-12"> <div><img src="80x150 image"/></div> <div><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy Policy</a></div> </div>
```

Comment: you should not advise to use obsolete attributes, dig into boostrap class and you will find the class that will fit the need ... before you start getting downvotes ;)